# template call is getting inside another template

Tags: xslt

I've the below XML data.

```
    <para><content-style font-style="bold">1/4 4.—</content-style>(1) In these Rules, unless the context otherwise requires, the following expressions have the meanings hereby respectively assigned to them, namely:
<orderedlist type="manual">
<item><para>“attend” includes the appearance by any person using electronic, mechanical or other means permitted by the Court;</para></item>
<item><para>“bailiff” includes the registrar, any clerk or other officer of the Court charged with the duties of a bailiff in the Subordinate Courts;</para></item>
<item><para>“Civil Procedure Convention” means the conventions set out in Appendix C to these Rules and includes any convention, treaty or agreement of any description or any provision thereof between different States relating to civil procedure in the court;</para></item>
<item><para>“folio” means 100 words, each figure being counted as one word;</para></item>
<item><para>“Form” means a form set out in Appendix A to these Rules, and a form so numbered in the Appendix;</para></item>
<item><para>“Judge” means a judge of the High Court or District Judge and includes, in cases where he is empowered to act, a Magistrate or the Registrar, as the case may require;</para></item>
<item><para>“officer” means an officer of the Supreme Court or Subordinate Courts;</para></item>
<item><para>“originating process” means a writ of summons or an originating summons;</para></item>
<item><para>“originating summons” means every summons for the commencement of proceedings other than a writ of summons;</para></item>
<item><para>“pleading” does not include an originating summons or preliminary act;</para></item>
<item><para>“receiver” includes a manager or consignee;</para></item>
<item><para>“Registry” means the Registry of the Supreme Court or the Registry of the Subordinate Courts, as the case may be, and references to the Registrar shall be construed accordingly;</para></item>
<item><para>“scheduled territories” has the meaning assigned to it by the Exchange Control Act (Chapter 99);</para></item>
<item><para>“Sheriff” includes a bailiff of the Subordinate Courts;</para></item>
<item><para>“sign”, in relation to the signing of documents by the Registrar, includes the affixing of a facsimile signature;</para></item>
<item><para>“solicitor” has the same meaning as in the Legal Profession Act (Chapter 161);</para></item>
<item><para>“summons” means every summons in a pending cause or matter.</para></item>
<item><para>“working day” means any day other than a Saturday, Sunday or public holiday;</para></item>
<item><para>“writ” means a writ of summons.</para></item>
</orderedlist></para>
```

here there is a `para` and `orderedlist` and when i run my template, the orderedlist is getting inside the para i.e. the `orderedlist` content is coming inside the `para` and after the the `orderedlist` template is getting called, i'm pretty confused why this is happening.

here is the [DEMO](http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaEP), please let me know how can i fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shown us which result you want but based on your match patterns it looks as if you currently want a template applied on `content-style` but your `call-template` processes the string value of the `para` element.

Therefore I have changed the code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="para" match="para">

<xsl:apply-templates select="./node()[1][self::page]" mode="first"/>

      <div>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./@align">
<xsl:attribute name="class">
                            <xsl:text>para align-</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./@align"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>    
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">
                            <xsl:text>para</xsl:text>

                        </xsl:attribute>    

                        </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>

            <xsl:when test="contains(./content-style[1],'/')">

            <div class="para">

             <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </div>
            </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:apply-templates/>  
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
      </div>



    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()">

    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(([Cc]hapter)\s(\d+))">

      <xsl:matching-substring>

          <xsl:value-of select="."/>

      </xsl:matching-substring>

          <xsl:non-matching-substring>

          <xsl:analyze-string select="."  regex="http://[^ ]+">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
         <a href="{.}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </a>

          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>

            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>

        </xsl:analyze-string>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>




    <xsl:template match="para/content-style[1]">

<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)">
<xsl:matching-substring>
<span class="phrase">
         <a name="{concat('P',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2),'-',regex-group(3))}"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
</span>
</xsl:matching-substring>
<xsl:non-matching-substring>
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)">
<xsl:matching-substring>
<span class="phrase">
         <a name="{concat('P',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2))}"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
</span>
</xsl:matching-substring>
<xsl:non-matching-substring>

    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>

</xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>    
</xsl:template>


 <xsl:template name="orderedlist" match="orderedlist">
        <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ol>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="item">
<!--<xsl:apply-templates select="./para[1]/node()[1][self::page]" mode="first"/>-->
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item/para">

<li class="item">
<xsl:variable name="strl">
<xsl:value-of select="string-length(../@num)"/>
</xsl:variable>

      <xsl:for-each select=".">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()[1][self::page]" mode="first"/>
      <div class="para">
      <xsl:choose>

<xsl:when test="name(../../parent::*[1]) = 'section' and $strl &gt; '2' and not(preceding-sibling::para)">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="../@num" mode="next"/>


</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>

<xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::para)">
<span class="item-num">
<xsl:value-of select="../@num"/>
</span>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:otherwise>



</xsl:choose>

       <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::para)]"/>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
    </li>

</xsl:template>






<xsl:template mode="next" match="@num">



 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)">
<xsl:matching-substring>
         <a name="{concat('P',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2),'-',regex-group(3))}"/>
    <span class="phrase">
    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
    </span>  
</xsl:matching-substring>
<xsl:non-matching-substring>
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)">
<xsl:matching-substring>
         <a name="{concat('P',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2))}"/>
    <span class="phrase">
    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
    </span>  
</xsl:matching-substring>
<xsl:non-matching-substring>

    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>

</xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>


<!--   <xsl:apply-templates select="../para"/></div>
      </li>-->

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page[not(preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::text()) or normalize-space()])]"/>






</xsl:transform>
```

which results in http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaEP/1 which outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <div class="para">
      <div class="para">
         <span class="phrase">
            <a name="P1-4"/>1/4</span> 4.—(1) In these Rules, unless the context otherwise requires, the following expressions have the meanings hereby respectively assigned to them, namely:
<ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“attend” includes the appearance by any person using electronic, mechanical or other means permitted by the Court;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“bailiff” includes the registrar, any clerk or other officer of the Court charged with the duties of a bailiff in the Subordinate Courts;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“Civil Procedure Convention” means the conventions set out in Appendix C to these Rules and includes any convention, treaty or agreement of any description or any provision thereof between different States relating to civil procedure in the court;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“folio” means 100 words, each figure being counted as one word;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“Form” means a form set out in Appendix A to these Rules, and a form so numbered in the Appendix;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“Judge” means a judge of the High Court or District Judge and includes, in cases where he is empowered to act, a Magistrate or the Registrar, as the case may require;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“officer” means an officer of the Supreme Court or Subordinate Courts;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“originating process” means a writ of summons or an originating summons;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“originating summons” means every summons for the commencement of proceedings other than a writ of summons;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“pleading” does not include an originating summons or preliminary act;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“receiver” includes a manager or consignee;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“Registry” means the Registry of the Supreme Court or the Registry of the Subordinate Courts, as the case may be, and references to the Registrar shall be construed accordingly;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“scheduled territories” has the meaning assigned to it by the Exchange Control Act (Chapter 99);</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“Sheriff” includes a bailiff of the Subordinate Courts;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“sign”, in relation to the signing of documents by the Registrar, includes the affixing of a facsimile signature;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“solicitor” has the same meaning as in the Legal Profession Act (Chapter 161);</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“summons” means every summons in a pending cause or matter.</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“working day” means any day other than a Saturday, Sunday or public holiday;</div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
               <div class="para">
                  <span class="item-num"/>“writ” means a writ of summons.</div>
            </li>
         </ol>
      </div>
   </div>
</root>
```

The main change was to simplify

```
    <div class="para">
     <xsl:call-template name="phrase"/><!--

     <xsl:variable name="content" select="generate-id(content-style[1])" />-->
     <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::content-style)]"/>
```

to

```
   <div class="para">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </div>
```

and to then remove the name and mode attribute on `<xsl:template name="phrase" match="para/content-style[1]" mode="phrase">` to get `<xsl:template name="phrase" match="para/content-style[1]">`. That way everything else falls into the right place. So basically the important step is to use apply-templates and matching templates as much as possible instead of trying to use `call-template`. If you need to or want to use `call-template` then keep in mind that it does not change the context node thus in a template matching `para` a `call-template` to a named template continues to process that `para` element.

Comment: Wow @Martin, Thanks you, this works like a charm, can you please explain a bit in detail where i went wrong and how you have fixed this? Thanks again

Comment: I have added some explanation on the changes I made.